# Automating selectize_input programmatically

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to reduce code duplication by writing [functions](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/shinymde/issues/15) to generate user interfaces.

However, it seems I am unable to create multiple `selectizeInput` elements with the arguments `selected` and `selectize` both set to `FALSE`. This is important because I need some elements initially set to `NULL` which can only be done this way.

Example that fails

```
library(shiny)
multi_selectize <- function(ids, titles, choices,size){
  Map(
    function(id, lab, choices,
             size) {
      selectizeInput(inputId = id,
                     label = lab,choices = choices,
                     selected = FALSE,selectize = FALSE,
                     size = size
      )
    },
    ids,
    titles,
    choices,
    size
  )
  
}
multi_selectize(c("test_0", "test_1"), titles = c("Test0","Test1"),
              choices = list(c("Lorem Ipsum", "Hello World"),
                             c("Ipsum Lorem", "World Hello")),
              size = c(1,2))
```

The above returns:

> Error in selectInput(inputId, ..., selectize = FALSE, width = width) :
> formal argument "selectize" matched by multiple actual arguments

The following works but is not what I need:

```
multi_selectize_ <- function(ids, titles, choices,size){
  Map(
    function(id, lab, choices,
             size) {
      selectizeInput(inputId = id,
                     label = lab,
                     choices = choices,
                     size = size
      )
    },
    ids,
    titles,
    choices,
    size
  )
  
}

multi_selectize_(ids=c("test_0", "test_1"), 
                 titles = c("Test0","Test1"),
                choices = list(c("Lorem Ipsum", "Hello World"),
                               c("Ipsum Lorem", "World Hello")),
                size = c(1,2))
```

Result from above:

```
$test_0
<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
  <label class="control-label" id="test_0-label" for="test_0">Test0</label>
  <div>
    <select id="test_0" class="form-control" size="1"><option value="Lorem Ipsum" selected>Lorem Ipsum</option>
<option value="Hello World">Hello World</option></select>
    <script type="application/json" data-for="test_0">{"plugins":["selectize-plugin-a11y"]}</script>
  </div>
</div>

$test_1
<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
  <label class="control-label" id="test_1-label" for="test_1">Test1</label>
  <div>
    <select id="test_1" class="form-control" size="2"><option value="Ipsum Lorem" selected>Ipsum Lorem</option>
<option value="World Hello">World Hello</option></select>
    <script type="application/json" data-for="test_1">{"plugins":["selectize-plugin-a11y"]}</script>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the first to work?

Comment: Is there a reason why Shiny modules wouldn’t give you what you want?

Comment: I tried modules but don't really see what advantage they play over plain functions. I am already using a package structure too. I would still need to write independent "ids"? https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

Comment: Let me see if I can come up with a demo…

Comment: Is `multi_selectize <- function(ids, titles, choices,size){
    Map(
        function(id, lab, choices,
                 size) {
            shiny:::selectizeIt(inputId = id,
                           selectInput(inputId = id,
                           label = lab,choices = choices,
                           selected = FALSE,selectize = FALSE,
                           multiple = TRUE,
                           size = size), options = NULL
            )
        },
        ids,
        titles,
        choices,
        size
    )
    
}`  an option?

Comment: @jpdugo17 Yes, seems so. This is what I use below and in the accepted answer?

Comment: It is based on @Limey's proposed function `selectizeIt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The souce of `selectizeInput` is

```
function (inputId, ..., options = NULL, width = NULL) 
{
    selectizeIt(inputId, selectInput(inputId, ..., selectize = FALSE, 
        width = width), options)
}
```

So the elipsis is passed directly from `selectizeInput` to `selectInput`.  But the call to `selectInput` *also* includes an explicit `selectize` argument.  So when you write

```
selectizeInput(selectize = FALSE)
```

the call to `selectizeIt` becomes

```
selectizeIt(
  inputId, 
  selectInput(inputId, selectize = FALSE, selectize = FALSE), 
  width=width, 
  options
)
```

Hence the error.

Im still working on the module demo, but may now leave it until the morning.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have switched to `selectInput` since this is not a performance stringent application. This seems to work as required.

```
multi_selectize <- function(ids, titles, choices,size){
  Map(
    function(id, lab, choices,
             size) 
      selectInput(inputId = id,
        label = lab,
        choices = choices,
        selected = FALSE,
        selectize = FALSE,
        size = size
      )
    ,
    ids,
    titles,
    choices,
    size
  )

}
```

Call:

```
multi_selectize(c("test_0", "test_1"), titles = c("Test0","Test1"),
              choices = list(c("Lorem Ipsum", "Hello World"),
                             c("Ipsum Lorem", "World Hello")),
              size = c(1,2))
```

Result

```
$test_0
<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
  <label class="control-label" id="test_0-label" for="test_0">Test0</label>
  <div>
    <select id="test_0" class="form-control" size="1"><option value="Lorem Ipsum">Lorem Ipsum</option>
<option value="Hello World">Hello World</option></select>
  </div>
</div>

$test_1
<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
  <label class="control-label" id="test_1-label" for="test_1">Test1</label>
  <div>
    <select id="test_1" class="form-control" size="2"><option value="Ipsum Lorem">Ipsum Lorem</option>
<option value="World Hello">World Hello</option></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

See @Limey's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70551892/10323798) explaining why `selectizeInput` fails.